# Heterogenous and Asymmetric Computing's differences

Tags: terminology, computer-architecture, parallel-computing

The definition of the both architecture looks pretty same. They are parallel computing architecture with different type of cores.

What distinguish their definition, actually?

Comment: What have you tried, to try to figure this out on your own?  Have you looked up the definitions of each?  Have you looked at some examples of each kind of architecture?  We like to see people make a serious effort to answer their question on their own before asking, and to show us in the question what they've tried (or what resources they've consulted, etc.).

Comment: I checked Wikipedia pages, they both defined close each other. I checked examples and I found the same example for both for some cases. I guess Heterogeneous computing is a certain example of asymmetric computing. The power consumption is emphasized more on HMP, and it could be the answer.

Comment: Neither are concretely defined terms.  They are both marketing terms for "not all the cores are the same."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heterogenous computing as opossite to homogenous or symmetric means that processing units differ, which is exactly the same as asymmetric (which is just not symmetric).
But there are more usage differences - asymmetric computing (processing) is more about different CPUs which are used to perform assigned tasks, in embedded systems this is by design, in general purpose by executing in given context, commonly about "local" environment.
Heterogenous is used to talk about tasks computed on different processing units (CPU, GPU and dedicated hardware), also used to describe distributed systems where processing takes place on totally random devices connected.

To make it full - symmetric means exactly the same vector, while homogenous is less strict and requires the results to be the same among devices (the same floating point representation), but does not require exact devices.

Comment: Thanks It was the answer actually I am looking for over 2 years.